# Property [bId] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel

I have a pages controller.I wanna get some information stored in my db when /myshopping requested.
This is my controller code :

```
public function myshopping()
    {
        $Buylist=DB::table('orders')->where('id','=',Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('oId','desc')->get();
        $Bookinfo=DB::table('books')->where('bId','=',$Buylist->bId)->first();
        return view('shop.myshopping',compact('Buylist','Bookinfo'));
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using`->get()` on a `QueryBuilder` returns a `Collection` (fancy wrapper for PHP arrays), so `$Buylist` is a group of records from your `orders` table, as opposed to a single record.

If you change your logic to use `->first()`:

```
$Buylist=DB::table('orders')->where('id','=',Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('oId','desc')->first();
```

Then you can access `$BuyList->bId` without issue (unless `$BuyList` returns `null`, but that's a different issue).